# Why Critical Updates dates are not consistent in sandbox and prodcution

Tags: release

Our team finding inconsistencies in the date reported from once instance and another on the release update.

How can be this improved and can the release updates be consistent for all the Org's.

We are also getting notifications about upcoming changes in email as well,Is there a way all the updates could be held in one place with definitive place for all release updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your concern about the inconsistent release update activation, I would say that it's safe to claim that the activation varies per instance, hence the inconsistency that you are seeing between your Sandboxes and your Production Org. Considering that you still have some time to check how the feature will impact your Org, you have the leverage to activate it and manually disable the update until it is auto-activated. Sometimes the activation gets postponed due to occurring bugs or feature enhancements. Usually, a release note pertaining to the critical update and why it was postponed will show after a major release has happened. It will also indicate as to when our Product Team plans to auto-activate it, which means that you'll have more time to test it out with the new release that just took place

As for the emails about upcoming Release Updates, Feature retirements, Chrome and Apple Privacy Updates, although all are pertaining to an update that will impact your Org (big or small), these are still different from one another. The best way to collate and keep track of the updates is to create separate folders in your email where you can store them and distinguishably review them.

Lastly, for the concern on how you can be notified of the change to the mandatory date or enforcement dates, as mentioned, you will sometimes see that the activation date is past-dated and will only get more information as to why once the release note regarding the specific critical update has been released. Furthermore, since you are receiving notifications about Major Release Reminders, there's a possibility that date is also embedded on the content of the email.

You can also check the below article to know the kind of updates you'll usually receive an email for.
Product & Service Notifications
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336830&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Now I understand that your main goal is to get a uniformity amongst the activations dates, emails, and so on, and with that, I would recommend posting an idea to ensure that our Product Team will be aware of such requests. You can do so via this link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's make sense.